# Prototype function overriden by other "class"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, node-assert

I have the following inputModel:

```
var UserCreateInputModel = function(req) {
    ...
    this.password = req.body.password;
    this.repeatPassword = req.body.repeatPassword;
    ...

    console.log(this.password !== this.repeatPassword);

    this.validate();
};
UserCreateInputModel.prototype = InputModel;

UserCreateInputModel.prototype.validate = function() {
    console.log('Validating...');
    if(this.password !== this.repeatPassword) throw new Error('Passwords are not equal!');
};

module.exports = UserCreateInputModel;
```

In my test I would like to test if the exception was thrown (using node's assert module):

```
//Act
assert.throws(function() {
    new UserCreateInputModel(req);
}, Error);
```

Somehow the exception is just not thrown. My console output from the constructor is "this".
On the console I don't see the output "Validating".

I guess this is some JavaScript pitfall or something like that (about this) but I'm just not getting the error ...

**Update**
I have another inputModel in another file. This "inherites" from `InputModel` too. So it seems `UserCreateInputModel.prototype.validate` is overridden in the other inputModel. Still don't get it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
UserCreateInputModel.prototype.validate = function() {
    console.log('Validating...');
    if(this.password !== this.repeatPassword) throw new Error('Passwords are not equal!');
};
```

is modifying the `InputModel` object. If you have two different types "inheriting" from `InputModel` with what you have here, and they both have `validate` methods, then one is overwriting the other.

To properly inherit from `InputModel`, use `Object.create()`:

```
UserCreateInputModel.prototype = Object.create(InputModel.prototype);
```

And then call the parent constructor from your child constructor:

```
var UserCreateInputModel = function(req) {
    InputModel.call(this, <arguments>);
```

This way, when you modify `UserCreateInputModel.prototype`, you will *only* be modifying `UserCreateInputModel.prototype` and not anything else.

Comment: If `InputModel` is constructor, you forgot `.prototype` inside `Object.create`. The convenience `util.inherits` does this for you plus sets `constructor` properly.

Comment: @herby I am suspending disbelief and assuming that OP got it mostly right and just left out `Object.create()`. It is entirely possible that `InputModel` itself is indeed the prototype that OP wants to use

Comment: Hm. Naming suggests otherwise, but only OP knows for sure. In my pessimism I can even imagine even the worse scenario: that dreaded "pattern" `SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();`, it may as well be that `InputModel` is such a full-blown instance. :-\ But it may as well be that I am just too pessimistic here.

Comment: @mosquito87 You've deleted the question you put here in the comments, but yes, there are disadvantages to using `new` to create a prototype. It creates a situation where every instance of the child type shares the _same instance_ of the parent type as their prototype, and this can lead to a lot of problems. You should use `Object.create` and then call the parent constructor from your child constructor. See also: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-object-create-improves-constructor-based-inheritance-in-javascript-it-doesn-t-replace-it.htm

Answer (score 0):

`UserCreateInputModel.prototype = InputModel` is not how you do inheritance. Who taught you this???!!!

It's:

- after the constructor, `util.inherits(UserCreateInputModel, InputModel)` (where `util` is `require('util')`), and
- inside the constructor, calling `InputModel.apply(this, arguments);` or `InputModel.call(this, <explicit list of input model ctr args>)`.

Get back with another EDIT if it still persists.